# How to get Visual Studio 2015 to work with Azure DevOps Git Repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2015

I have to use Visual Studio 2015 to support BizTalk 2016. We are looking to convert from TFS to a GIT repository hosted on Azure DevOps, and it maybe a year or more before we upgrade BizTalk.

I've tried a few things, but seem to be running in circles. In the Team Explorer of Visual Studio 2015, I see the option to connect to GitHub, but not sure that is compatible with Azure.  The tool I have seems to connect with GitHub and not other Git repositories like Azure, BitBucket, GitLabs etc...

[image]

Is there a different generic or Azure specific module to install for VS 2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems very strange to me.  I'm not sure if you can connect from Visual Studio, BUT... you can open Visual Studio from Azure DevOps. Click "Clone" then choose the https (I didn't try SSH yet), then for the "IDE" select "Clone in Visual Studio"

[image]

After that, you can go do your Clone or other GIT functions, or to go "Manage Connections" which now looks like this:

[image]

NOTE However - that if you have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed, it might pick the latest version.  It did not offer the "picker" to select which version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of connecting to GitHub, which is another provider of hosted Git Repositories, use the "Manage Connections" button to connect directly to Azure DevOps or TFS, that should list available git repositories on Azure DevOps and the ability to clone those.

Make sure you create the repository in Azure DevOps first.

You can also click the "clone" option in the "Local Git Repositories" section at the bottom of the panel and directly enter the clone url of the repository.

Comment: That might work in later Visual Studio - but does it work in VS2015?  How does 2015 know about Azure which might have been created later?  There must be a module or something to install?

Comment: Ok, I re-read.  I will try the Clone under "Local Git Respos".  I thought I had to connect first.

Comment: I haven't had VS2015 installed for ages. So I'm trying to remember the exact steps. I'd recommend to not use the built-in features of VS2015, as it's a very old implementation. You can easily run VS2019 or a 3rd party git client along side VS2015.

Comment: Are you saying to run VS2019 just for the purposes of GIT, when we do all our development in VS2015?  VS2019 is not even on the VM I'm using, but I guess we could install it.  I tried the clone, but cannot get user/validated.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-will-no-longer-support-alternate-credentials-authentication/  I would like to use the token, but need to find setup for that, if I'm on the right path.

Comment: For that matter, I guess we could use the GIT command line.  Or I'll check https://tortoisegit.org/, which we used someplace I worked in the past.

Comment: I found some magic clicks that kind of work, see my other answer.  I also got TortoiseGit working, after having to install PUTTY to reference my private key.